# Does SharePoint support video streaming?

Tags: media-streaming

I want to upload large videos in sharepoint document library and play it in media player webpart. Does it support streaming by default?

If not, Please let me know how to design such a solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes and No.

- There are issues with uploading large blobs in sharepoint (say 2gb limit), IIS timing out on you, network through-put, etc.

What I did:
1. Created a IIS directory for the folders where the videos are and made sure browse folder is enabled (in IIS)
2. Added a media webpart to a webpart page and supplied the weblink to the video to this webpart.

Comment: This is very similar to the solution I typically use. Custom IIS site to host the video, and a web part player solution to actually handle the playback/rendering of the video. I do not use the OOTB video web part, because it's Silverlight based and thus doesn't work on iPad's (and some other tablets). I typically use a HTML5 video player with fallback to Flash for IE compatibility.

Comment: I want user to upload videos as well. They don't have permissions on file system

Comment: Unless you have some sort of an RBS solution, it doesn't make a lot of sense to upload video into SharePoint in general. If you have a 200mb video that gets broken out into binary data and stored in SQL. The resulting performance hit is potentially pretty high (unless you have very well thought out architecture that's planned for this scenario). You're also limited by the max upload file size on the web application (though that's a soft/configurable value).

Comment: my bad. yes, I use CEWP and use following script to host my videos.

<div align="center"><embed width="600" height="400" src="http://MediahostingServer:12000/Making%20the%20Most%20of%20401K%20session%203%202012.wmv" type="video/x-ms-wmv" autoplay="false" loop="false"></embed>&#160;</div>